# Alternative to placing scalar function in Where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, indexing, user-defined-functions

I have a stored procedure that accepts a string and compares it to several fields. However, one of the fields contains additional characters that need to be removed before comparing it to the search string.

e.g.

```
Create Or Alter Proc FindPosts3
(
     @criteria AS nvarchar(25)
)
AS
Begin

     Select P.OwnerUserId,P.CreationDate,p.Score,p.CommentCount,p.Body1
     From Posts1 p Inner Join
     (
         Select p.OwnerUserId,max(p.CreationDate) as CreationDate
         From Posts1 p
         Group by p.OwnerUserId

     ) Sub On P.OwnerUserId = Sub.OwnerUserId AND P.CreationDate = Sub.CreationDate
     Where p.Score = @criteria OR p.CommentCount = @criteria Or udfstripHtmlTags(p.body1) = @criteria   

End
```

Sample field values are:

```
OwernerUserID---CreationDate----Score----CommentCount----Body
1               Aug 20, 2010     18      6               <p>null<p>
2               Dec 15, 2008      7      3               <b>variable<b>
3               Mar 07, 2011     15      20              <i>Arrays<i>
```

When searching the body field, the `<p>, <b> and <i>` tags are removed using the udfStripHtmlTag function. This causes the Body field in the where clause to no longer be a '`SARG`' or Search Argument which slows down the query.

In this example, I am removing HTML tags from the body field using a function called 'udfStripHtmlTag' before comparing it to the criteria. As is expected this causes an index scan to occur instead of an index seek with an index that was created for the body field. As a matter of fact, this also causes the indexes for the score and `commentcount` fields to no longer be used in this version of the query. In another version where I use union instead of 'or', the indexes for the score and `commentcount` fields are still used. However, the query is still just as slow because of the index scan for the body field.

Stripping the characters from the field is a requirement. Is there an alternative technique I can use instead of the scalar function in the where clause?

nb. This is not my original problem code. Rather it is code based on the StackOverflow database. My original problem code is based on a lot of sensitive data/fields so it was easier for me to use an alternative database. Likewise, the body field in the StackOverflow database was changed to `nvarchar(30)` so I could create an index for it. Finally, the query runs in less than a second without the scalar function.

Comment: Table-Valued Functions tend to be more performant, but sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: _Stripping the characters from the field is a requierement._ This is the source of your problem. if you need to search it and you need to strip the html from it to search, then do it ONCE when you insert or update that column.

Comment: _This is not my original problem code_ Then any suggestions you might receive might be completely off-base.

Comment: @SMor, Even though it's not my original problem, I was able to replicate the same performance issues. The problem lies in the function in the where clause. If I can solve it here, it also solves my original problem. Also, your suggestion is correct about doing it when updating or inserting. However I can't modify the original database. I am only writing queries to retrieve data.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I added a table, I don't know if that is helpful. However, the results I am getting back are fine. It's just that the function causes the index not to be used which results in the query taking about a minute and a half to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is any more performant than your scalar function

Tired of extracting string, I modified a parse function to accept two unlike delimiters.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([OwernerUserID] int,[CreationDate] varchar(50),[Score] int,[CommentCount] int,[Body] varchar(150))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Aug 20, 2010',18,6,'<p>null</p>')
,(2,'Dec 15, 2008',7,3,'<b>variable</b>')
,(3,'Mar 07, 2011',15,20,'<i>Arrays</i>')
 
Select A.* 
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](Body,'>','</') B
 Where B.RetVal like 'variable%'
```

**Returns**

```
OwernerUserID   CreationDate    Score   CommentCount    Body
2               Dec 15, 2008    7       3               <b>variable</b>
```

**The Table-Valued Function if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delim1 varchar(100),@Delim2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                  ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
            From  ( values (convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delim1,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>').query('.'))) as A(XMLData)
            Cross Apply XMLData.nodes('x') AS B(i)
          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I need. My query now executes in under a second while searching over 4 million records. It's weird that many online resources advise against using scalar functions in where clauses but do not offer a viable alternative. This solution should work in a wide variety of scenarios for me. Thanks again.

Comment: To be clear, the logic in your table valued function did not matter. I created a tvf with my own logic then used cross apply. I then compared the return value from cross apply to my criteria the same way the example did.